# Flutter Webview throws compiling error -ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView location: class InputAwareWebView

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-web

I am using Webview  version

> webview_flutter: ^2.0.6

The android studio while running throws this error and stop the build

**Os Version**

minSdkVersion 19

targetSdkVersion 30

> A:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\InputAwareWebView.java:31:
> error: cannot find symbol   private
> ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView proxyAdapterView;
> ^   symbol:   class ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView   location: class InputAwareWebView
>
> A:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\InputAwareWebView.java:112:
> error: cannot find symbol
> new ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView(
> ^   symbol:   class ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView   location: class
> InputAwareWebView Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated
> API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 2 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 10):

ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView has wrong extension .jav
just change it to .java until the flutter team release the fix.

Please refer to the github link for the issue

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82800

Answer (score 1):

As Ravi stated, renaming the file extension to `.java` does the trick.

The file can be found at:

`{your flutter folder}\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView.java`